# What is the official Sails teams recommendation for running tests?

Tags: sails.js

Is there a library/framework for Sails testing?

I don't know if there are some similarities with rails in this regard. But rails has a testing framework by default. Does sails have the same?

I've heard of Jasmine. But wanted to know what the sails team recommends.

Comment: Go ahead and answer that too while your looking at it Scott :)
And yes, I know this will be deleted, just having fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't officially recommend one testing framework over another; in general our only official policy is "testing is good and you should do it!".  Any testing framework that works with Node (and especially Express) will be good for testing your Sails app.

That being said, the core Sails tests use [Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/).  Examining the code to those core tests, especially [certain integration tests](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/test/integration/router.specifiedRoutes.test.js), will give you some insight into how to test a Sails app.  The biggest difference between the core integration tests and what you might see in a project-level test is that the core tests create a new app on the fly, while for a project you'd just be testing the code you have.

We're also toying around with [automatic test generation](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-generate-test), although it's safe to say it's in its infancy.  Then again, this is open source, so who's to say when a hero might come along and make a valuable contribution!

Comment: Great, I'll check out Mocha too.